# Code sign failures submitting iOS Adobe Air app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, air, app-store, adobe, codesign

I'm hoping someone may have a solution or suggestions that will fix this issue for me. I have an iPhone app I've created using Adobe Flash Pro CS6 with Adobe Air 3.4. It runs fine on my iPhone when I build it using the distribution cert and the adhoc distribution mobile provision file. When I build for app-store release using the distribution cert and the appstore mobile provision file, the ipa compiles fine, but when I try to submit it to iTunes Connect via Application Loader, I get:

"Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /Users/Admin/Downloads/sizablesend143.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive"

When I do as some suggest and rename the ipa as a .zip file, unzip, and then rezip the .app file within the Payload folder and upload that way, I get:

"Unable to run the lipo command: /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platfor m/Developer/usr/bin/lip: Can't map input file: /var/folders/mh/pz30_kmx6530_cdg7w0hqr9c0000gn/T/SizableSend.app/Siza bleSend (Invalid argument)"

"Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains diallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate"

"Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure SizableSend is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned."

I've tried compiling directly via adt command line on windows, compiling via adt command line on the Mac itself, compiling through Flash Pro CS6, all result in the same errors. I've also completely regenerated all certs and provisions from the top, starting with generating a new csr from Keychain Access tool on my Mac, and making sure the old certs were removed. I'm completely stumped and really hoping someone can shed some light on how I can fix this issue.

Thank you so very much in advance,
Alex